# InnoDB: error: space object of table

Tags: mysql, innodb, linux, recovery

```
131212 10:35:18  InnoDB: error: space object of table 'main/wp_m_membership_levels',
InnoDB: space id 119 did not exist in memory. Retrying an open.
131212 10:35:18  InnoDB: error: space object of table 'main/wp_m_membership_rules',
InnoDB: space id 122 did not exist in memory. Retrying an open.
InnoDB: Database page corruption on disk or a failed
InnoDB: file read of page 5.
InnoDB: You may have to recover from a backup.
131212 10:35:18  InnoDB: Page dump in ascii and hex (16384 bytes):
```

I placed InnoDB into recovery mode 4 but had no luck fixing the errors.

Is there any other tricks I can/could try or do I need to restore from a backup?